# MonoTouch.Dialog Removing Lines at end of table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

In the below screenshot I have a table but only a few elements. How do I tell MonoTouch.Dialog to not draw the extra lines at the bottom of the table when there aren't enough StyledStringElements to fill the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1. You set the `UITableView.SeparatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None`. However you will lose all separators (between all cells, not just at the bottom). OTOH That can be a good thing if you want to have your own custom separator.
2. You set an empty footer view to your `UITableView`, something like:

   `tv.TableFooterView = new UIView ();`

You might want to select your own color (or clear) and not the default one.

Comment: The TableFooterView "hack" is brilliant. I would have started messing around with the height of the view frame and it would still probably work but it is so much more moving parts.

Comment: I has found also that the TableFooterView  is the optimal solution.

Comment: when click row to move to another view, and then comeback, the line at the end of tableview visible again. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.(iOS Native)

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Not sure how to write it in MonoTouch.

Comment: Not sure how to do it in MonoTouch? Look at the other answer.